# Sum every 30s in R, multiple groups, irregular observations per group, retain metadata within each new row

Tags: r, aggregate

I am working with a dataframe that has 8776 rows and 15 variables.

Here is the head of a subset of the columns:

```
    head(subsetFishData)
    TextTime TransectName Relief Complexity CopperRF KELPGREENLING LINGCOD 
    1 17:10:07  Annapolis_1     NA         NA        0             0       0           
    2 17:10:08  Annapolis_1     NA         NA        0             0       0           
    3 17:10:09  Annapolis_1     NA         NA        0             0       0           
    4 17:10:10  Annapolis_1     NA         NA        0             0       0           
    5 17:10:11  Annapolis_1     NA         NA        0             0       0           
    6 17:10:12  Annapolis_1     NA         NA        0             0       0
```

These are the headings of each column from the dput output (full output was really long and mostly zeroes/NAs):

```
    dput(FishData)

    "TextTime", "TextTimeDecimal", "ProjectName", "TransectName", 
    "Relief", "SpeciesID", "Complexity", "FieldOfView", "CopperRF", 
    "KELPGREENLING", "LINGCOD", "QuillbackRF", "TigerRF", 
    "YELLOWTAILROCKFISH"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8776L))
```

There are ~15 categories of `TransectName` and the number of rows in each group is irregular(between 456 and 1053)/not divisible by 30.

Data was collected every second under `TextTime`, this data is only chronological within transect group.

In the above example, I would like to aggregate the data by summing every 30 values for  `CopperRF`, `LINGCOD`, and `KELPGREENLING`,  while retaining metadata that are consistent throughout each `TransectName` group, for example `Relief` and `Complexity` will have the same value throughout each `TransectName` grouping. Essentially aggregating every 30 values of the last few columns within each group of `TransectName`, shortening the dataframe to ~290 rows.

I have read quite a few threads on summing data every n rows to aggregate, however they are much more simplified than my situation and nothing has worked for me yet.

So far I have been trying to find a solution in dplyr.

This failed:

```
    FishData %>%
    mutate(cleanTime =
    strsplit(TextTime, ":") %>%
    sapply(function(x){
    x <- as.numeric(x)
    x[1] + x[2]/60 + x[3]/(60*60)
    })
    , roundTime = floor(cleanTime * 2)/2  )
```

I also tried creating a matrix using:

```
    fish.matrix <- data.matrix(FishData, rownames.force = NA)
```

and using colSums() to aggregate but the groups werent divisible by 30.

I am thinking I should start by grouping by "TransectName" and possibly use summarise to somehow sum every 30s in the last 6 columns of my dataframe... I'm just having difficulty figuring out the code for this.

```
    FishData %>% 
    group_by(TransectName, roundTime) %>%
    summarise( = sum())
```

Hopefully that is enough info to explain what I'm trying to get at.

Thank you,
Dez

Comment: What criteria would you use forsumming the 30 values?

Comment: Do you want to aggregate every 30 values within each group of `TransectName`, or over the whole dataset? And could you use `dput()` to provide the example data?

Comment: What did you tried till now (can you share some code) ? Can you give a reproductible exemple (use dput() for give a data sample) ? And a view of your desired results ?

Comment: Hi there, I updated my description to hopefully make it more understandable. I want to aggregate every 30 values within each group of `TransectName`.  I tried using `dput()` and the output was too long to display so I pasted the bottom section in the description. I also put some of the code I tried, though its probably very wrong and terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit

Given your more detailed question, I think I can address the whole problem now.

Reproducible example:

```
# prepare minimal dummy data.frame
DF <- mtcars
DF$g1 <- rep(letters[1:8], 4)
DF$keep1 <- rep("A", nrow(DF))
DF$keep2 <- rep(c("B", "C"), 16)

# desired operations:
# group, keeping extra information
# mutate to add second grouping variable per first groups.
# group again, keeping extra information
# sum multiple desired variables
DF %>%
  group_by(g1, keep1, keep2) %>%
  mutate(hi = rep(1:10, each = 3, length.out = n())) %>%
  group_by(hi, g1, keep1, keep2) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(gear, carb), sum)
```

Your case:

```
# your case probably reads something like below
FishData %>%
  group_by(TransectName, Relief, Complexity) %>%
  mutate(SummingIndex = rep(1:300, each = 30, length.out = n())) %>%
  group_by(TransectName, SummingIndex, Relief, Complexity) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(CopperRF, KELPGREENLING, LINGCOD), sum)
```

---

#### Original answer below

You are asking several questions at once. I will reply to how you can **retain metadata** with `aggregate`. See the illustrative example below - you can simply add the extra fields (`keep1` and `keep2` in the example) to the grouping variable (`g1` in the example), since they would not affect the grouping.

```
xx <- mtcars

xx$g1 <- rep(letters[1:8], 4)
xx$keep1 <- rep("A", nrow(xx))
xx$keep2 <- rep(c("B", "C"), 16)

aggregate(xx[, c("gear", "carb")], by = xx[, c("g1", "keep1", "keep2")], FUN = sum)
```